# ANOVA For testing homogeneity of means

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics

If ANOVA tests the homogeneity of means then why the test statistics involves the standard deviation ... F=MSSE/MSST only involves variance ... is there anyone who knows the logic behind it?

Comment: As you move the means further apart but keeping the distribution within the groups the same you will increase the between groups variance.

Comment: Mdewey could u explain please

Comment: You are dividing the between by the within to get F (I do not know what your symbols mean). So if you hold within constant and increase between then F increases.